# How can I add multiple google calendars to the calendar?

Tags: calendar

I have been able to add my main Google Calendar to the calendar app, but I cannot add secondary calendars. I have attempted to `sudo apt-get install evolution-data-server-pantheon-online-accounts` but it comes back saying there is no package. Any help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is currently a [Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/maya/+bug/1356869) that you can only add one calendar of your Google account.

But you can add multiple Google Calendars to Maya via CalDAV.

[image: Add CalDav Calendar]

URL: `https://apidata.googleusercontent.com/caldav/v2/`**calendarID**`/events`

User: is your email-address

The calendarID is your email (for your main calendar).
For other calendars you can find it in your Google Calendar > Settings > Calendars > Choose your calendar and then under Calendar Address in brackets.

[image: find Google CalendarID]

Comment: Does this still work? I couldn't reproduce this using the latest stable release ...

Comment: It looks like Google has changed the URL. See https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/caldav/v2/guide#connecting_to_googles_caldav_server

Maybe it's still working with the new URL. I haven't test it yet.

Comment: This didn't work for me in Loki,k neither did the method proposed by @Benni. Although maybe I simply did something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Maya Calendar, also knows as Calendar, has a plugin named maya-calendar-plugin-google, installed by default.

You can go to options and add multiples accounts.

In order to add them, they must configured to thirdy party applications.

Look at:

[Google Calendar Support](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37648)

Answer (score 2):

The solution proposed by Benni might have worked in the past, but I could not reproduce it with Loki.

In the other hand, the solution proposed by Giovanni Milanesi worked perfeclty and allowed me to have multiple calendars within Maya.

I reproduce bellow the steps (credits goes to him):

1. Open Google account and create an App Password
2. Open Google Calendar, go to settings of the single calendar you want to see and copy the **calendar ID** (it's something like iislfkjsldjfsdljslsflkslksdfs8@group.calendar.google.com )
3. Open Elementary calendar and click "add new calendar")
4. Choose "Google" as calendar type, fill whatever name you want and in the **user field** paste the calendar ID
5. When it asks for authentication fill it with your **google username** and the **app password**
6. DONE!

You can repeat the steps to add every calendar you want to see

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround to show multiple calendars

https://github.com/elementary/calendar/issues/16#issuecomment-423436392

Comment: Great, worked for me too!