# Can't configure shared google calendar in Maya?

Tags: calendar, settings

Has anyone being able to configure shared google calendar in Maya Calendar application?

I have tried few things:

- Add personal calendar (this only add my own calendar but not other that are shared in my account)
- Add shared calendar using the Calendar ID provided by Google (Not working). Authentication failure.
- Add following Caldav configuration. In Thunderbird with lightening we should use xml address. I tried with xml and http nothing worked. Always says Authentication denied.
- I have also configured the calendar as public for testing propose. Same thing.

I have tried to see if it is a way to debug Maya Calendar application, but I haven't found any log files.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: did you already tried this way (http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/862/227) to add the calendar via CalDAV?

Comment: Can you confirm whether you're trying to add a shared calendar *in addition* to your main/personal calendar? If so, the problem is not that it's a shared calendar, but that you can't add multiple calendars (for now, due to a bug), as explained in the answer mentioned by @Benni.

Comment: Yes, that is the post mentioned above resolved the issue. Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not available in Maya at the moment. As per your first attempt, you can only sync the application with your main calendar connected to your Google account.

See [this answer in Maya's launchpad page](https://answers.launchpad.net/maya/+question/265089) for confirmation. I also see a possible workaround there, but personally I haven't tested it.