# Maya basic usage

Tags: release-loki, calendar

I'm trying to import a calendar from my google agenda, so I enabled not secure application (https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) to use my google account, but the password seems to be always wrong for maya (but it's not of course !).
Then I have downloaded a ICS file from another web site and opened with calendar but nothing appends, nothing is imported.

So, I dont realy know why ...

also tryied [How can I add multiple google calendars to the calendar?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/860/how-can-i-add-multiple-google-calendars-to-the-calendar/862#862)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Do you have 2-factor authentication enabled on your Google account?

Comment: No I haven't (https://www.google.com/landing/2step/ ? )

Answer (score 2):

You may need to [enable "less secure apps"](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) in your Google settings. For more details, see [this answer regarding a similar problem with Pantheon Mail](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1990/gmail-geary-doesnt-meet-modern-security-standards/2031#2031).

Maya and Geary do not support OAuth, which Google now requires by default. Hopefully, a future Pantheon Online Accounts release will add OAuth support. Until then, enabling "less secure apps" should do the trick.

For more details, see the [Google CalDAV API docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/caldav/v2/guide#connecting_to_googles_caldav_server).

Answer (score 0):

You may use it with 2-factor authentication enabled (if you need it for other reasons) after generating an app password for Maya.

Comment: I activated 2-factor authentification with my phone, and I generate a new password for my calendar but nothing appends ...
No error, No sync.
The eOS mailer works with my google account currently (so less secure app are enabled).